# Installation of libogg file on OS X giving error

Tags: macos, makefile, installation, permission-denied

I am trying to install `libogg` file. I am getting following error.

```
Making install in src
.././install-sh -c -d '/usr/lib'
/bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libogg.la '/usr/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libogg.0.dylib /usr/lib/libogg.0.dylib
install: /usr/lib/libogg.0.dylib: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 71
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need administrator privilege to install items in `/usr/lib` which is a system directory.

If you ran the command `make install` to get the result shown above, run the command:

```
sudo make install
```

and enter your administrator (root) password when prompted to write to the system directory.

It's somewhat unusual for open source software to install itself in `/usr/lib`, much more common to use `/usr/local/lib` but that's a different question.